# Tried to install github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql but there's an error when I tried importing

Tags: go, mysql-connector

First i created a folder called sqltest the run the go mod init. And then I installed the mysql by running the code below

```
go get -u github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql
```

[image]

However when I tried to import "github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql, it has an error
it says `could not import github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql (no required module provides package "github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql")compilerBrokenImport`

[image]

I tried to delete the go-sql-driver and re-install it but nothing happens

Comment: What is your environment ? What's the content of your go.mod file ? What exact comment did you run ? Can you provide a minimal go file which reproduces the error ?

Comment: Hi, edited my post and put some pictures in there

Comment: Have you tried running that without the -u flag, that's to update a package.

Answer (score 0):

Does the import look like?

```
import (
_ "github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql"

)
```

Comment: yes its the same as that one

Comment: Have you executed `go mod tidy` ?